# Don't talk gibberish, I don't talk gibberish

Tags: word-usage

Someone replied to a question I asked( on a website).

He wrote:
Ajjdj skidid sksksko......

So I said:

> Sorry but I **don't talk** gibberish.

Is the use of "talk gibberish" natural?

Can it be:

> Please **don't talk** gibberish.

Is it a natural alternative for "speak"(of course colloquially).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. That is a normal thing to say. I suspect how normal it is, and the relative prevalence of *talk* vs *speak*, depends on dialect. For British English, that's normal, though people might frown on it in formal writing. It probably exists because *talk* would be normal when referring to the content, rather than the language:

> You don't half **talk** a lot of rubbish.

(There are other British English dialect features there, like *don't half*, which is an emphatic.)

Answer (score 4):

Yep, “talk gibberish” is totally fine.

Answer (score 3):

To talk can mean simply mean to utter, whereas to speak can mean that also, (e.g. speak fast, speak loudly, speak nonsense) or it can mean to understand a language (e.g. speak French), and 'speak gibberish' could have either of these meanings, and is thus ambiguous.